# SSAS List roles and dimension permissions (RLS) from Analysis Services

Tags: powershell, ssas, olap, cube, olap-cube

I'm trying to get all the roles from Analysis Services and their dimensions permissions.

I have already been successful, managing to extract users and their roles, however I have not found anywhere if it is possible to extract permissions by dimensions.

I need this listing, because we are creating a permissions dimension from SSAS, in a data warehouse.

The script below on the second picture, I got from here: [Extract SSAS Roles and user](https://powerbloggerbi.com/2016/06/20/extract-ssas-roles-and-user/), but I already tried from "Lucas Notes" aswell: [List SSAS User Roles Using PowerShell](http://www.lucasnotes.com/2012/09/list-ssas-user-roles-using-powershell.html#comment-form) and [PowerShell Script: List SQL Server Analysis Service Role Permission By Database and Cube](http://www.lucasnotes.com/2015/04/powershell-script-list-sql-server.html)

I really don't understand anything about PowerShell script, so here's what I've tried:

What I'd like to list aswell (permission to a certain data, or column, or value from a dimension):

[image: Dimension permission]

What I've already managed to list:

[image: PowerShell script and result]

Comment: How about using DMVs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions, something like TMSCHEMA_TABLE_PERMISSIONS seems promising

Comment: @Gigga If I run `SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_TABLE_PERMISSIONS;` in a MDX query it returns me nothing, not even the columns. If I run `SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET('MSOLAP','DATASOURCE=FCESPSQLD007; Initial Catalog=OLAP_Oracle;',
    'SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_TABLE_PERMISSIONS');` in a SQL query, it returns no rows, but with the columns. If I run any DMV with `MDSCHEMA` in a MDX query, it works great. So I think I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @guilherme_matheus, didn't look close enough to notice you are using multidimensional cube. Here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/92044534-afb6-4c6c-a8ba-7d91d87614fd/need-to-extract-ssas-role-permissions-for-a-given-cube-role?forum=sqlanalysisservices it says you could extend your powershell to get necessary information using the AMO objects as you have already done. There should be a CubePermissions -object under Database.Cube, here's the objectmodel: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/amo/amo-concepts-and-object-model?view=asallproducts-allversions

Comment: @Gigga I think you gave me a path, I already did some scripts on PowerShell to get PowerBI and Sharepoint data, but on SSAS I think it's to hard for that and there is not much content on web aswell. Can you help me please? Do you know how to make this script?